# Resize MediaPlayer without play button controls

Tags: delphi, activex, ole, windows-media-player

I wanted to code a resizeable WindowsMediaplayer (ActiveX) without the play controls. it should fit to TPanels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to work this out a while ago, and after lots of googling i found this to work

Put a WindowsMedaiPlayer object on the Panel, and setting its align to alclient,
the player control area can be hidden with `uiMode := 'none'`, set in the ide or code

then assigning the Panels resize event with

```
uses Ole2;

procedure TForm1.Panel1Resize(Sender: TObject);
 const
    IID_IOleInPlaceObject: SYSTEM.TGUID = '{00000113-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}';
 var
  IOIPObj: IOleInPlaceObject;
 begin
  SYSTEM.IDispatch(WindowsMediaPlayer1.OleObject).QueryInterface(IID_IOleInPlaceObject, IOIPObj);
  IOIPObj.SetObjectRects(Panel1.ClientRect, Panel1.ClientRect);
 end;


procedure TForm1.Play;
 begin
  WindowsMediaPlayer1.uiMode := 'none';  //show no interface, this can be set from the ide
  WindowsMediaPlayer1.URL := 'movie.mpg';
  WindowsMediaPlayer1.stretchToFit := True;
  WindowsMediaPlayer1.Controls.play;
 end;
```

Adapted from http://our.obor.us/node/1999

Ole2 is for IOleInPlaceObject, i had to add `$(Delphi)\source\rtl\Win` to the library path for delphi to find it.

(delphi 7, wmp 11)

**Extra:** Something a bit *easier* to use

```
uses Ole2; 

procedure SmoothResizeMediaPlayer(aMediaPlayer: TWindowsMediaPlayer; PosRect,ClipRect:Trect);
const
  IID_IOleInPlaceObject: SYSTEM.TGUID = '{00000113-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}';
var
  IOIPObj: IOleInPlaceObject;
begin
  SYSTEM.IDispatch(aMediaPlayer.OleObject).QueryInterface(IID_IOleInPlaceObject, IOIPObj);
  IOIPObj.SetObjectRects(PosRect, ClipRect);
end;
```

and Called with

```
  SmoothResizeMediaPlayer(WindowsMediaPlayer1, panel1.ClientRect, panel1.ClientRect);
```